# How can I print characters like ♟ in python

Tags: python, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to print a clean chess board in python 2.7 that uses unique characters such as ♟.

I have tried simply replacing a value in a string (`"g".replace(g, ♟)`) but it is changed to `'\xe2\x80\xa6'`. If I put the character into an online ASCII converter, it returns "226 153 159"

Comment: Why would you put utf-8 into an ascii converter?

Comment: I just wanted to see what it'd output really. Possibly something useful but I think not.

Comment: It's not an ASCII character, it's a UTF-8 character.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that it was a UTF-8 character.

Comment: Just use `print u'♟'`

Comment: Its not a utf-8 character, its a unicode character. In python 2, if you want to do this you want to use unicode strings throughout as much of your program as you can. For example, `print u"g".replace(u"g", u"♟")`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That helped.

Comment: The ASCII encoding condtains fewer than 100 printable characters. This character is not part of that set. You have to use unicode to represent it.

Comment: utf-8 is the de facto standard for representing unicode text in binary form. If you have to save your text as a file, or send strings as data over the internet, you should use utf-8. If you only use the string inside a single python script, you should not have to worry about that. In python 3 all strings are unicode, which is great when you have to deal with characters such as this one, or text which is not English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`♟` is a unicode character. In python 2, `str` holds ascii strings or binary data, while `unicode` holds unicode strings. When you do `"♟"` you get a binary encoded version of the unicode string. What that encoding is depends on the editor/console you used to type it in. Its common (and I think preferred) to use UTF-8 to encode strings but you may find that Windows editors favor little-endian UTF-16 strings.

Either way, you want to write your strings as unicode as much as possible. You can do some mix-and-matching between `str` and `unicode` but make sure anything outside of the ASCII code set is unicode from the beginning.

Python can take an encoding hint at the front of the file. So, assuming you use a UTF-8 editor, you can do

```
!@/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

chess_piece = u"♟"
print u"g".replace(u"g", chess_piece)
```